# Logical indexing python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am working on improving the speed of logical indexing in Python. So, currently I have to plot some heatmaps, for which I am divinding the inputs data into specified number of x and y bins, and then through the function **return_val**, I am using logical indexing to compute the mean value in a given bin

This works well when my bin size is small, but when I try to increase the bin size, to let say 100x100, then the program slows down quite a lot

I know that the speed could be increased by using the stats.binned_statistic_2d function in Python. However, I would like to understand how can I optimize my current code in order to make the averaging process go quicker

```
import numpy as np

arr_len = 932826
x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=4496, size=arr_len)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-74, high=492, size=arr_len)
z = np.random.uniform(low=-30, high=97, size=arr_len)

# Check points
bin_x = 10
bin_y = 10
x1 = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), bin_x)
y1 = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), bin_y)


def return_val(x, y, z, x1, y1, i, j):
    idx = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(x > x1[i - 1], x < x1[i]), np.logical_and(y > y1[j - 1], y < y1[j]))
    if np.count_nonzero(idx) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return np.mean(z[idx])


z1 = np.zeros((len(x1), len(y1)))
for i in range(1, len(x1)):
    for j in range(1, len(y1)):
        z1[i - 1, j - 1] = return_val(x, y, z, x1, y1, i, j)

z1 = z1.transpose()
```

Comment: usually main problem are `for`-loops - they slow down code a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half the time spent by the code is in implicitly *allocating temporary arrays* (due to `logical_and` and comparison operators) and another half the time is spent in the *slow nested loops calling a function* with the slow CPython *interpreter*. One way to overcomes these issues is simply to **use the Numba's JIT** using branchless operations without temporary arrays and using **parallelism**. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

arr_len = 932826
x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=4496, size=arr_len)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-74, high=492, size=arr_len)
z = np.random.uniform(low=-30, high=97, size=arr_len)

# Check points
bin_x = 10
bin_y = 10
x1 = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), bin_x)
y1 = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), bin_y)

@nb.njit('float64(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], int32, int32)')
def return_val(x, y, z, x1, y1, i, j):
    count = 0
    s = 0.0
    # Branchless mean
    for k in range(len(x)):
        valid = (x[k] > x1[i - 1]) & (x[k] < x1[i]) & (y[k] > y1[j - 1]) & (y[k] < y1[j])
        s += z[k] * valid
        count += valid
    if count == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return s / count

@nb.njit('float64[:,:](float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(x, y, z, x1, y1):
    z1 = np.zeros((len(x1), len(y1)))
    for i in nb.prange(1, len(x1)):
        for j in range(1, len(y1)):
            z1[i - 1, j - 1] = return_val(x, y, z, x1, y1, i, j)
    return z1

z1 = compute(x, y, z, x1, y1)
```

The above code is **11 times faster** on my machine. It can be improved further by working on loops so that the computation can be more *cache-friendly*.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant response. It will be really helpful in future when I have to do complex calculations